# How can I get Spock to run with @Transactional?

Tags: spring, groovy, spock

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve in a test

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [MockConfig])
@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyDbService.class])
class MyDbServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def "it gets an error if the row is already locked"() {
        when: "a row is locked, then the thread sleeps to simulate work"
        Thread.start {
            myDbService.lockRow(1)
            Thread.sleep(60000)
        }

        // try to lock the exact same row
        myDbService.lockRow(1)

        then: "it should thrown an exception"
        def ex = thrown(Exception)
    }

    // MockConfig here
}
```

The query behind `myDbService.lockRow()` is just a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`

It looks like Spock is running both of those calls in a single `@Transactional`, so the second call won't fail.

How can I get that first call to `lockRow` to run in a separate transaction, so the second one will error?

Comment: Spock doesn't do any transactional handling, that is all done by Spring. Without using any synchronization, like `CountDownLatch` it is perfectly possible for the test to finish before the second thread even started. Without seeing more of your code, it is not really possible to give a better answer.

Comment: I would doubt there's a transaction at all unless you configure a transaction manager in your `MockConfig`.  When you pass a `classes` argument to `SpringBootTest`, it spins up very little in the way of Context.